# JavaScript's equivalent code for Ruby's range

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
a = (2000..Date.today.year).to_a
```

In Ruby, above expression returns `[2000, 2001, ...snip..., 2018]`

I would like to know equivalent JavaScript code.

```
a = Array.from({length: new Date().getFullYear() - 2000 + 1}, (_, i) => i + 2000)
```

This can be an answer, but I'm looking for better code in terms of

- Wider browser support without polyfill than above code
- Shorter code like specifing start and end as Ruby's one (My JS example is ugly since I wrote `2000` twice).

A code which satisfies either one is helpful.

EDIT

I would like to use value `a` in Vue.js's v-for loop in inline manner like

```
<option v-for="year in a" :value="year">FY{{year}}</option>
```

So single expression is desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simplest** (but not shortest) solution would be to use a loop:

```
a = []; 
for (var year = new Date().getFullYear(); year >= 2000; --year) 
    a.unshift(year);

>>>> [2000, 2001, ..., 2017, 2018]
```

or perhaps to define a function:

```
function range(from, to) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = from; i <= to; ++i) res.push(i);
    return res;
}
```

The **tricky** solution would be like this:

```
function range(from, to) { 
    return [...Array(to - from + 1).keys()].map(function(x){return x + from});
}
```

---

EDIT: If you are really determined, you can make everything an expression:

```
(function(a, b){return [...Array(b-a+1).keys()].map(function(x){return x+a;})})(2000, new Date().getFullYear())
```

:)

Comment: I thought ES2015+ has more straightforward way, but apparently it does not.. Thank you anyway.